# Dr. Frankenbull's Problem: How To Tell Aurochs From Bison

Tags: science-based, science-fiction, species, skeletons

The mad scientist community is...mad, to put it kiddie-appropriately.  Their logic has the tendency to make 0% sense 100% of the time (provided, of course, that they ever bring it up.)

So you can imagine a field scientist's confusion when the community tasked him to imagine a hybrid between a wild bison (they never specified which species) and a wild aurochs through their bones alone because hybrids between wild bison and ***domesticated*** aurochs are so done before.  The problem with that is that the scientist has observed only live bison and never once studied their skeletons, and he had never seen a live wild aurochs.  (In fairness, ***NO ONE*** has seen a live wild aurochs for roughly three centuries.)  In short, he couldn't tell the two species apart just by looking at their bones.

In order to save his skin, he would need help from a higher power (that's us.)  So, comprehensively speaking, just by looking at the bones alone, how would the field scientist differentiate a wild bison from a wild aurochs?

Comment: They are closely related, so it will be hard. from looking at wiki entries for both, it seems aurochs has horns that are longer and pointed forward, while bison has a larger rib cage.

Comment: Also, why is this mad science? We have tiger-lion hybrids IRL ...

Comment: @BaldBear: They are not that closely related (different genera, *Bos* and *Bison*).  And they do not look particularly similar. An aurochs looked pretty much like a rugged kind of domestic cattle, mid-size to large-ish (but definitely smaller than the large breeds we have today, and visibly smaller than a bison).

Comment: Easy, assuming your sample available for examination contains only aurochs & bison just look for a pulse, if it has one it's definitely a bison, if it doesn't it may be an auroch.

Comment: @Pelinore: It's an auroch**s** (on the model of German *Auerochse*, from Proto-Germanic *\*ūraz*, aurochs, and *\*uhsô*, ox).

Comment: @AlexP : Oops! thanks, my bad.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### They are fairly easy to tell apart from just bones.

From the bones there are several obvious differences. Well start from the most obvious and work down.

the shape of the skull is an easy one and the first thing you look at in mammals. bison skulls are much wider/shorter proportionally and have smaller horns. Even a damaged skeleton will show this obvious difference. below we have an american bison skulls followed by an auroch skull. the difference holds true for european bison although the difference is smaller.

[image]
[image]

Between the american bison and the auroch there is a big difference in the hump which is much larger in bison and has a much stronger down curve in the thoracic spine and the position of the neck is much lower, again this difference is less pronounced in european bison but still noticeable. This also gives aurochs a much more horizontal profile.

General size can also be an indicator, american bison are bigger, but of course this only works if you are sure you have an adult. and the difference is almost nonexistent with european bison. If they only have a few bones this could easily lead to them being confused.

Auroch tails are longer, not that you are likely to find all the tail bones. I am sure someone who specializes in pleistocene mammals can spot a few more differences.

Skeleton of an auroch and bison.

[image]

[image]

http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.534.6285

Answer (score 5):

I am not good to the bones, but if I look at [pictures/reconstruction](https://prehistoric-fauna.com/Steppe-bison-and-Auroch) of the two species, I can tell a difference:

[image: bison and auroch compared]

the horns make a big difference between the two.

And I suspect even the way they connect to the skull is peculiar.

So, go for the head!

Comment: Bison's "posture" is more slumped too, so the head sits lower than shoulderblades.

Comment: Horns are a variable

Answer (score 2):

**The European "bison" is such a hybrid.**

[image: European bison]

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_bison

> The European bison (Bison bonasus), also known as wisent (/ˈviːzənt/
>   or /ˈwiːzənt/) or the European wood bison, is a Eurasian species of
>   bison. It is one of two extant species of bison, alongside the
>   American bison.... Analysis
>   of mitochondrial genomes and nuclear DNA revealed that the wisent is
>   theoretically the result of hybridization between the extinct Steppe
>   bison (Bison priscus) and the ancestors of the aurochs (Bos
>   primigenius) since their genetic material contains up to 10% aurochs
>   genomic ancestry; the possible hybrid is referred to informally as the
>   Higgs bison...

The steppe bison gave rise to the American bison and so presumably represents a more pure bison strain.  The European "bison" is actually the hybrid you desire - an acient mix between auroch and bison.  Possibly your mad scientist lived in the Pleistocene?

Comment: Extinct bison don't apply here.

Comment: Higgs bison - I saw what you did there... :-)

Answer (score 2):

The most obvious difference in the skeleton along the "hump".

As you can see from L.Dutch's image the bison has a more pronounced hump over the shoulders. While that is primarily muscle, it has a skeletal structure that is significantly more pronounced in the bison than the aurochs.